# IE 10, 11 background-size issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-image

Checkout my demo page here
http://maze.andmorestuff.com/
I've set the background size to 100% 100% which is working fine in all browsers except the Internet Explorer 9, 10, 11. Here is the Css:

```
body {
  color: #5c5c5c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/themescdn/52fe33b4a9b5f3dshowroom01.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

Can you tell me why it's not working on IE? Or can you suggest a fix for this issue?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `background-size` is supported in IE9+ (so this isn't the problem)

The problem is the body has no height.  Giving `<html>` a 100% height worked for me, but you can also make it work by adding a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to the body, so that floated descendants are cleared.

Screenshot:

http://linenwoods.com/test.jpg

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But adding height 100% didn't fix the problem. No I've added a clearfix and it's working fine. Thanks